# Android - replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a min activity it has two layout.

```
-----------Root Layout------------
-                                -
-           Layout 1             -
----------------------------------
-                                -
-           Layout2              -
----------------------------------
```

I replace mainActivity to fragment using `getSupportFragmentManager`, it works. Replace code is below :

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(rootLayoutId, fragment);
```

But I try to replace not all page only a spesific layout like below:

```
 childFragMan = fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
 childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
 childFragTrans.add(layout1ID, subFragment);
 childFragTrans.addToBackStack(to);
 childFragTrans.commit();
```

My exception message is here :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1560)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:696)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:662)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at io.smartface.plugin.SMFJSObject.callAsFunction(Native Method)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at io.smartface.plugin.SMFJSObject.callAsFunction(SMFJSObject.java:271)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at io.smartface.android.SFProxyInvocationHandler.handleMethodInJS(SFProxyInvocationHandler.java:40)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at io.smartface.android.SFProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SFProxyInvocationHandler.java:22)
06-08 18:46:15.022 5290-5290/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
```

Comment: check where you adding your fragment `childFragTrans.add(fragment.layout1ID, subFragment);` it's illegal state, post your full logic.

Comment: why ileegal? I want to put my fragment only a spesific layout. Fragmant and main actibity inflate same layout on my case.